# Етимологія ім'я “Святослав”

Tags: етимологія, власні-назви

Зацікавила для власного розвитку та розширення кругозору етимологія ім'я “Святослав”. На диво отримав достатньо малу кількість інформації.

Досить коротенька стаття у Вікіпедії наводить [таку](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2) етимологію:

> Святосла́в — слов'янське чоловіче ім'я, що походить слів «святий» і «слава».

Мовознавець, доктор філологічних наук Олександр Пономарів, професор Інституту журналістики Київського національного університету імені Тараса Шевченка, який дає поради стосовно стандартів сучасної української літературної мови в своєму блозі на ресурсі BBC Ukrainian досить коротко згадує про дане ім'я у своїй статті "**[Більшість імен прийшли в українську з інших мов](http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/ukrainian/ponomariv/2010/11/post-34.html)**":

> З дохристиянських імен українського походження в нас лишилися "Людмила", "Світлана", "Володимир", "Всеволод", "*Святослав*" та інші на "-слав", кальковані з грецької "Богдан", "Богодар", "Віра", "Надія", "Любов" та деякі інші.

Також, зі згаданої статті профессора з'ясовується, що *Святослав* - це семантично прозоре ім'я:

> ...Коли Олег уважає, що майже всі імена в нас питомі українські, то хай пояснить, що означають на українському ґрунті, скажімо, імена "Олена", "Григорій", "Наталя", "Сергій", "Іван", "Марія", "Ольга". 
>   Це важко, на відміну від імен семантично прозорих - "Людмила", "Світлана", "Святослав" та інших.

Этимологічний онлайн-словник російської мови Макса Фасмера [зазначає](https://vasmer.lexicography.online/%D1%81/%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA):

> **Святопо́лк** род. п. -а (м.) — имя собств., др.-русск. Святопълкъ (Пов. врем. лет), цслав.-греч. Σφεντόπλικος (Жит. св. Климента), чеш. Svatopluk, польск. Swiętopeɫk. Образовано от свято́й и полк, т. е. «имеющий благочестивое войско» (Миклошич, Bildung 95 и сл.) **Аналогично Святосла́в,** Σφενδοσθλάβος (Конст. Багр., Adm. imp.); см. Томсен, Urspr. 57. Менее приемлемо предположение о заимствовании Святопо́лк из гот. swinÞa-fulks «validum ехеrсitum habens» (Шлейхер, KSchl. Beitr. 2, 482); см. Миклошич, там же [О дохрист. образовании этих имен см. Якобсон, IJSLP, ½, 1959, стр. 269. — Т.]

Отже, які ще існують пояснення походження даного імені?
Чи існують якісь особливості вживання цього імені в українській мові?

Answer (score 3):

> **Святослав** - давнє слов'янське особове ім'я, складене з основи
>   прикметника **свят**- "сильний, святий" та основи -**слав**. На думку
>   Г.Півторака, це ім'я створила давньоруська княгиня Ольга, дружина
>   Ігоря Рюриковича, для свого сина, бажаючи підкреслити свою етнічну
>   приналежність у варязькому оточенні. Ольга скалькувала
>   англо-норманські імена двох попередніх київських князів, Олега (Helgi-
>   **святий**) та Ігоря (Ingvar, що з Ingvio - **бог достатку**, varr -
>   **охороняти**). Так Ольга склала двоосновне ім'я **Святослав**.

Думку Г. П. Півторака передав П. П. Чучка в своєму творі "Слов'янськi особовi iмена украïнцiв: iсторико-етимологiчний словник", де я й знайшла цю [цікавинку](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=M-sHKtbjF2EC&pg=PA315&dq=%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2).

Answer (score 1):

[Етимологічний словник української мови 5 том](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/EtSlUkrM_2006/EtSlUkrM_2006.pdf) ст. 200

[image]

Словник-довідник ["Власні імена людей"](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/cgi-bin/ua/elib.exe?Z21ID=&I21DBN=UKRLIB&P21DBN=UKRLIB&S21STN=1&S21REF=10&S21FMT=online_book&C21COM=S&S21CNR=20&S21P01=0&S21P02=0&S21P03=FF=&S21STR=ukr0001272)

> **Святослав** слов., від *свят- (святий)* і *слав- (слава)*. Святко, Святусь;
>   Слава, Славко, Славцьо, Славик, Славчик.

Answer (score -2):

На мою думку, Святослав - це той, хто славить Святого, тобто Бога. Або ж славить святість. Другий корінь "слав" походить від слова "славити". А далі "слава - славуни - слав'яни - слов'яни".

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Наші критерії якості дещо відрізняються від того, що можна побачити на мовних форумах і блоґах. Необґрунтовані відповіді базуються лише на думці їхнього автора і тому викликають хвилю диспутів і заперечень. А якісні відповіді ґрунтуються на якісних джерелах: словниках, поважних сайтах тощо. Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [answer] а також [«Якими мають бути гарні відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/). Ви завжди можете виправити відповідь, зробивши її більш аргументованою. Для цього натисніть [edit].